# I want to average the numbers inputted into the ArrayList, however it only calculates average as 0.0

Tags: java, arraylist, average

It sums perfectly fine, however it averages the values as 0.0 no matter what numbers I input. How can I make it output the correct average value?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculation {
    static Toolkit tools = new Toolkit();
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        double average = 0.0;
        double sum = 0;
        int i =0;
        int num = 0;
        int nElements = 0;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter value: ");
        num = console.nextInt();
        while(num != 0) {
            value.add(new Integer(num));
        }

        for(i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
             sum += value.size();
        }
        average = sum / value.size();
        System.out.println("Number of values read: " + value.size());
        System.out.println("Values sum: " + sum + "Values average: " + 
                            average);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(num != 0) {  value.add(new Integer(num));  }` This will be an infinite loop because you don't change `num` once you are inside so the condition can never become false. I'm not sure how you verified that the sum is working correctly as you claimed.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I forgot to add `num = console.nextInt();`into this code. However, after I added it, it sums the numbers yet still calculates the average as 0.

Comment: When I run the code with that line added, the sum is incorrect but the average of the incorrect sum is correct. If I enter 5, 5, 5, 0 I get a sum of 9.0 and average as 3.0. Again, I am not sure how you are seeing what you see as the code you posted does not do what you describe.

Comment: Here's a curious line:  `sum += value.size()`

Comment: Ya, you don't want to add the size of the list to your sum, you want to add the current value to your sum `sum += value.get(i)`

Comment: I copied this code and got the right answer. I must have changed the other code and failed to see it. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as is now, the loop will only end if you enter `0` the first time otherwise it will lead to an infinite loop. rather, you'll need to read the next integer within the loop as such:

```
while(num != 0) {
    value.add(new Integer(num));
    num = console.nextInt();  // add this line
}
```

Also, change this:

```
sum += value.size();
```

to this:

```
sum += value.get(i);
```

as you'll want to reduce the numbers inside the `ArrayList` into a single value rather than performing the summation of the `ArrayList`'s size on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

What Aomine said is correct. However, it is not the only problem. Inside your for loop you are adding the size of your Arraylist to your 'sum' variable. You should be adding the values it holds instead, i.e. summing them.

```
double average = 0.0;
    double sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter value: ");
    num = console.nextInt();
    while (num != 0) {
        value.add(new Integer(num));
        num = console.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
        sum += value.get(i);
    }
    average = sum / value.size();
    System.out.println("Number of values read: " + value.size());
    System.out.println("Values sum: " + sum + "Values average: " + average);
```